# Location tracking in android

Tags: android, location, tracking

I have been trying consistent location tracking code in my application.

But it always fails in doze mode and some devices. Location tracking does not work smoothly in all types of android devices

Can anyone tell me a perfect solution or code to track user location irrespective of the state of device and it should work on all kind of android devices

What i have tried so far...
Job scheduler

Work manager

Forground service

Background service

Alarm manager

push Notification

But all of these fails at some point on some devices
None of them is perfect
They stop working in sleep mode or doze mode and sometimes they do not work at all

Can any one suggest a tested and a bug free solution?

Comment: is continuous background service is your requirement whether app is running or not ?

Comment: yes,continuous background service